# customize multiple select won't work in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, multipleselection

I copied a code where it works good in mozilla but, when i go to chrome it doesn't work correctly. I have this in mozilla, where it works like it is an input type where when you type the start letter, the select box will show something like it suggest.

Here is the code :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2" id="labelcheck-up" for="fname">Diagnosis:</label>
<div class="col-sm-2">                              
    <select name="tdiagnosis[]" id="tdiagnosis" class="form-control select2"  multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Please input diagnosis here">                                  
        <option value="Dog">Dog</option>                                  
        <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="Goat">Goat</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>               
</form>
```

Here is jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40338/

Any suggestions how to make this work in google chrome? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what does not work correctly?

Comment: hi @AlexanderO'Mara thanks for your immediate response. Please run the jsfiddle in mozilla. and it will show you how it works. thanks

Comment: I think thats only because of browser settings, may be you have enabled cookies or anything in mozila but not in google chrome. I think you should upload screenshots of error in case anyone dont have access to another browser

Comment: I'm not noticing a difference between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response guys. wait i'll edit it a bit.